# How do you make a join in Hibernate return a list instead of a two-dimensional list?

Tags: hibernate, join, hql, inner-join

Hopefully, this is a simple question.

I'm doing a join in HQL along the lines of:

```
FROM Apple a, Orange o WHERE a.price = o.price AND a.price > 1.99
```

When I do this, I get back a collection representing the join.  However, each element in the collection is actually another collection containing the related apple and orange.

What I want is a list of apples and what I'm getting is a list of apples and oranges.  Logically, I'm looking for:

```
All apples priced greater than 1.99 only when
there is also an orange at the same price.
```

My actual problem is 50X more complex than this but I've simplified it to the basic problem.  How do I correct/modify this HQL query to only give one type of object?

Comment: did you try something like 'select apple a from....'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your query slightly:

```
SELECT a
FROM Apple a, Orange o WHERE ...
```

Comment: I tried that before posting and it didn't work.  When I get a chance, I'll do it again and post the errors I get.  Our architecture is fairly complex so the error could be elsewhere but it would be good to know, at least, that adding the select statement SHOULD work...

Comment: I was getting a null pointer exception. Turned out, the reason was that I had typed "SELECT Apple" instead of "Select a".  Knowing that this should, in fact, work helped to find the problem... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

After leaving my comment I went to the documentation.  Here is an example theta join from the docs

```
select p from NameList list, Person p
where p.name = some elements(list.names)
```

so it seems what you are doing should definitely be possible

Comment: Thanks for responding. That example is unrelated because there is only one object involved (Cat).  My problem here is that there are two separate objects in the join and both are being returned, when I desire only one in the list I get back.

Comment: @gmale, updated my answer with the next example, which involves more than one object ;).  Have you looked at the HQL chapter? ;)

Comment: I've read lots of online HQL resources but none actually dug into the details of the data structures returned from the join queries (multi-dimensionaly lists or not). So I wasn't sure if the problem was coming from HQL or from 50 other possible factors in our code base. Turns out, if you accidentally enter "SELECT person" instead of "SELECT p" you get a non-descript null pointer exception. In my case, there was no stack trace with it so it made things REALLY confusing. Thanks for taking time to respond. +1

Comment: " That example is unrelated because there is only one object involved (Cat)."

Yeah, I really hate that about those examples.